# Index of intersection of two subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$ with indices $3$ and $5$ in $G$.

I need to show that the index of $H\cap K$ is a multiple of $15$.

ATQ

$\frac{|G|}{|H|}$ = 3

So $|G|$ is  a multiple of $3$.

Similarly, $|G|$ is a multiple of $5$.

So we conclude that $|G|$ is a multiple of $15$.

Now $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $G$. So by Lagrange's theorem , it will divide $|G|$.

From here, how can I conclude that its order is a multiple of $15$?

Comment: You are not told that the group is finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*. $[A : C] = [A : B] [B : C]$ for (finite) groups $A$ with subgroups $B ⊆ A$ and $C ⊆ B$.

Comment: Does the result still hold if $G$ is infinite?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I will delete my comment! I am afraid that I frequently get irritated when people (apparently) assume that groups are finite. In fact your hint remains true if you delete the word "finite".

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes, the result generally follows from $A / C \cong \bigsqcup_{B / C} A/ B$, see [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Index_is_multiplicative). However, the questioner tagged this question [tag:finite-groups], so we may assume that all groups are finite, offering a more direct, less technical way of proving the statement in the hint.